# Getting Internal error while creating index in azure cosmos

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

i tried to apply index in my azure cosmos db with command db.test.createIndex({"syncDate": -1}) but it is giving me internal error.

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question to provide additional details. As written, it's difficult to know what's going wrong (or even what your error is). Did you try executing `db.test.createIndex()` from the `mongo` cli? If so: did you confirm that you connected, and could list your databases and collections?

Comment: Thankyou David , I was able to solve my query @DavidMakogon

Comment: @ishita.jain can you share, how you solved this